# Tidy evaluation programming and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

Trying to write a relatively simple wrapper to produce some plots, but can not work out how to specify tidy evaluation of grouping variables specified as `...` an example function that facets variables but doesn't distinguish by grouping...

```
my_plot <- function(df = starwars,
                    select = c(height, mass),
                    ...){
    results <- list()
    ## Tidyeval arguments
    quo_select <- enquo(select)
    quo_group  <- quos(...)
    ## Filter, reshape and plot
    results$df <- df %>%
                  dplyr::filter(!is.na(!!!quo_group)) %>%
                  dplyr::select(!!quo_select, !!!quo_group) %>%
                  gather(key = variable, value = value, !!!quo_select) %>% 
                  ## Specify what to plot
                  ggplot(aes(value)) +
                  geom_histogram(stat = 'count')  +
                  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free', strip.position = 'bottom')
    return(results)
}
## Plot height and mass as facets but colour histograms by hair_color
my_plot(df = starwars, select = c(height, mass), hair_color)
```

Great it works, but how to distinguish between different `hair_color`?  Normally this is done within `aes()` but since this is using the results of `quos()` (i.e. `quo_group`) I should (I think) be using `aes_()` instead

```
my_plot <- function(df = starwars,
                    select = c(height, mass),
                    ...){
    results <- list()
    ## Tidyeval arguments
    quo_select <- enquo(select)
    quo_group  <- quos(...)
    ## Filter, reshape and plot
    results$df <- df %>%
                  dplyr::filter(!is.na(!!!quo_group)) %>%
                  dplyr::select(!!quo_select, !!!quo_group) %>%
                  gather(key = variable, value = value, !!!quo_select) %>% 
                  ## Specify what to plot, including colouring by the supplied ... groupings
                  ggplot(aes_(~value, colour = !!!quo_group)) + 
                  geom_histogram(stat = 'count')  +
                  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free', strip.position = 'bottom')
    return(results)
}
## Plot height and mass as facets but colour histograms by hair_color
my_plot(df = starwars, select = c(height, mass), hair_color)
Error in !quo_group : invalid argument type
```

I can't see or work out having read [Programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) several times now where I'm going wrong.

Can anyone point out my error/show me the way?

Comment: In your second function, why do you have two lines with `ggplot(aes(etc.))` ?

Comment: If you use `quo(...)` instead of `quos(...)` then things work OK in `aes_` a la `aes_(~value, color = quo_group)`.  But maybe you need a list of grouping variables for something else?

Comment: Oh, I see, `quos` returns a list.  So if you only want to use the first element of the 1 element list that get from `quos(...)`, you'd need `color = quo_group[[1]]` in `aes_`.

Comment: @FlorianGD an error transcribing the two versions, now corrected.

Comment: @aosmith `quo_group[[1]]` does the trick, but seems at odds to the [Programming with dplyr : capturing multiple variables](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#capturing-multiple-variables) documentation.

Comment: @slackline I agree, but I'm not sure how capturing multiple variables fits in with mapping single variables to aesthetics.  It seems like for variable mapping you'd only want to capture a single variable, and that you'd have a specific argument for this in your function.  I guess maybe we'll see once ggplot2 is moved to the tidy evaluation framework!

Comment: @aosmith yes, I'm going to have to re-jig the options to my function.  Looking forward full details of tidyeval in ggplot2.

Comment: see here my man https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824409/how-to-combine-ggplot-and-dplyr-into-a-function

Answer (score 3):

The new released [`ggplot2 v3.0.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/) supports `!!` inside `aes()`. With some minor modification, your function is now working

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_plot <- function(df = starwars,
                    select = c(height, mass),
                    ...){
  results <- list()

  ## Tidyeval arguments
  quo_select <- enquo(select)

  # only need quo here, if quos is used then we need to `unlist` to 
  # convert its output from list to vector
  quo_group  <- quo(...) 

  ## Filter, reshape and plot
  results$df <- df %>%
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(!!!quo_group)) %>%
    dplyr::select(!!quo_select, !!!quo_group) %>%
    gather(key = variable, value = value, !!!quo_select) %>% 
    ## Specify what to plot, including coloring by the supplied dots `...` 
    ggplot(aes(value, color = !!quo_group, fill = !!quo_group)) +  # unquote inside aes
    geom_histogram(stat = 'count')  +
    facet_wrap(vars(variable), scales = 'free', strip.position = 'bottom')
  return(results)
}

## Plot height and mass as facets but color histograms by hair_color
my_plot(df = starwars, select = c(height, mass), hair_color)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thanks, I'd clocked that ggplot2 v3.0.0 solved a lot of these problems, only downside for me is I've switched jobs and as a consequence had to start using Python instead :-/

Comment: Now you know both `Python` and `R`. Isn't that great? Congratulations!

Comment: I wouldn't say I know Python yet but I'm getting there ;-)  Understanding design patterns and SOLID principles are also a concurrent learning curve!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Does this satisfy the requirements?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

your_plot <- function(df, select, color=NULL) {

  df <- as.data.table(df)[, mget(na.omit(c(select, color)))]

  ggplot(melt(df, color, select), aes_string(x=quote(value), color=color)) +
    geom_histogram(stat="count") +
    facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free", strip.position="bottom")

}

your_plot(dplyr::starwars, c("height", "mass"), "hair_color")
```

This uses `melt` to stack the `select` variables, with the `color` variable(s) repeated for each stack.  It also uses `aes_string`, since `aes(x=value, color=color)` fails when `color=NULL`.