# Programming with ggplot2 and dplyr

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to combine `dplyr` and `ggplot` within one function using piping and struggling with some issues now.

Here is the first easy one which is working. Function which takes a dataframe and filters by a specified column and value.

```
foo <- function(df, y, t = 4){
  tmp <- df %>% 
          filter(!!enquo(y) > t)
  ggplot(tmp, aes_(substitute(y))) + 
      geom_histogram()  
}
foo(mtcars, cyl)
```

Now I'm trying to pipe directly to the ggplot function...gives an error

```
foo <- function(df, y, t=4){
  df %>% 
     filter(!!enquo(y) > t) %>% 
        ggplot(aes_(substitute(y))) + 
            geom_histogram()  
}
foo(mtcars, cyl)
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation

and the last one. How to add a facet?

```
foo <- function(df, y, gr, t=4){
  df %>% 
       filter(!!enquo(y) > t) %>% 
  ggplot(aes_(substitute(y))) + 
      geom_histogram() +  
      facet_grid(~gr)
}
foo(mtcars, y= cyl, gr= vs)
```

#### Edit

The second issue can be solved using `aes_q` instead of `aes_` & `substitute`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824409/how-to-combine-ggplot-and-dplyr-into-a-function)

```
foo <- function(df, y, gr, t=4){
  y <- enquo(y)
  df %>% 
    filter(!!y > t) %>% 
       ggplot(aes_q(y)) + 
           geom_histogram()
}
foo(mtcars, cyl)
```

Using `ggplot2_2.2.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ggplot2 v3.0.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/) released in July 2018 supports `!!` (bang bang), `!!!`, and `:=`.

`facet_wrap()` and `facet_grid()` support `vars()` inputs. The first two arguments of `facet_grid()` become `rows` and `cols`. `facet_grid(vars(cyl), vars(am, vs))` is equivalent to `facet_grid(cyl ~ am + vs)` and `facet_grid(cols = vars(am, vs))` is equivalent to `facet_grid(. ~ am + vs)`.

So your example can be modified as follow:

```r
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

foo <- function(df, y, gr, t=4) {
  y <- enquo(y)
  gr <- enquo(gr)

  df %>% 
    filter(!!y > t) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(!!y)) + 
    geom_histogram() +  
    facet_grid(cols = vars(!!gr))
}

foo(mtcars, y= cyl, gr= vs)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

@Tung's answer can be simplified using `{{` syntax. https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

foo <- function(df, y, gr, t = 4) {
  df %>% 
    filter({{ y }}> t) %>% 
    ggplot(aes({{ y }})) + 
    geom_histogram() +  
    facet_grid(cols = vars({{ gr }}))
}

foo(mtcars, y = cyl, gr = vs)
```