# Passing weights to glm() using rlang

Tags: r, glm, rlang, tidyeval

I want to pass `weights` to `glm()` via a function without having to use the `eval(substitute())` or `do.call()` methods, but using `rlang`.

This describes a more complicated underlying function.

```r
# Toy data
mydata = dplyr::tibble(outcome = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                                group = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
                                wgts = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
)

# This works
glm(outcome ~ group, data = mydata)                             

# This works
glm(outcome ~ group, data = mydata, weights = wgts)                             

library(rlang)
# Function not passing weights
myglm <- function(.data, y, x){
    glm(expr(!! enexpr(y) ~ !! enexpr(x)), data = .data)
}

# This works
myglm(mydata, outcome, group)

# Function passing weights
myglm2 <- function(.data, y, x, weights){
    glm(expr(!! enexpr(y) ~ !! enexpr(x)), `weights = !! enexpr(weights)`, data = .data)
}

# This doesn't work
myglm2(mydata, outcome, group, wgts)
```

(Ticks are to highlight).

I know the weights argument here is wrong, I have tried many different ways of doing this all unsuccessfully. The actual function will be passed to a version of `purrr:map()` or `purrr:invoke()`, which is why I want to avoid a simple `do.call()`. Thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `glm()` can recognize an expression being provided to its `weights` argument, but doesn't support quasiquotation, because it uses the base `quote()` / `substitute()` / `eval()` mechanisms instead of `rlang`. [This causes problems for nested expression arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700912/why-is-enquo-preferable-to-substitute-eval/53215820#53215820).

One way to get around it is to compose the entire `glm` expression, then evaluate it. You can use `...` to supply optional arguments.

```
myglm2 <- function( .data, y, x, weights, ... ) {
  myglm <- expr( glm(!!enexpr(y) ~ !!enexpr(x), data=.data, 
                      weights = !!enexpr(weights), ...) )
  eval(myglm)
}

myglm2(mydata, outcome, group)
# Call:  glm(formula = outcome ~ group, data = .data)

myglm2(mydata, outcome, group, wgts)
# Call:  glm(formula = outcome ~ group, data = .data, weights = wgts)

myglm2(mydata, outcome, group, wgts, subset=7:10)
# Call:  glm(formula = outcome ~ group, data = .data, weights = wgts, 
#     subset = ..1)
# While masked as ..1, the 7:10 is nevertheless correctly passed to glm()
```

To follow @lionel's suggestion, you can encapsulate the expression composition / evaluation into a standalone function:

```
value <- function( e ) {eval(enexpr(e), caller_env())}

myglm2 <- function( .data, y, x, weights, ... ) {
  value( glm(!!enexpr(y) ~ !!enexpr(x), data=.data, 
              weights = !!enexpr(weights), ...) )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Artem, that's great and gets me some way. Can you think of a way to make arguments optional in the same framework. Along the lines of this (not working): 
`myglm2 <- function( .data, y, x, ...) {
  args = list2(...)
  myglm <- expr( glm(!!enexpr(y) ~ !!enexpr(x), 
    data=.data, !!! args) )
  eval_tidy(myglm)
}
myglm2(mydata, outcome, group, weights = wgts)`

Comment: I would extract the expr + eval thing in a function (e.g. `value <- function(expr) eval(enexpr(expr))`). Then you can do `value(glm(!!enexpr(y) ~ !!enexpr(x))` which is a bit nicer. No need for `eval_tidy()` because `glm()` won't handle quosures well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @lionel. `function(e) {eval(enexpr(e))}` was giving me `cannot coerce class ‘"rlang_fake_data_pronoun"’ to a data.frame` error. I was able to get around it with using `eval_tidy(enquo(e))` instead.

Comment: Hmm... This error is very surprising, perhaps you made a typo? By the way, just pass the dots directly, don't use `!!!enexprs(...)`. It is especially bad to splice dots captured to bare expressions rather than quosures because you lose the correct environments. If you pass the dots directly, it looks cleaner and is more robust and accurate.

Comment: @lionel: I think the `rlang_fake_data_pronoun` error is related to `.data`, whose scope is limited to `myglm2()`, so `eval()` inside `value()` sees the `rlang::.data` pronoun instead. `enquo()` addresses it effectively, by capturing `myglm2`'s environment. Regarding, `!!!enexprs(...)`, I agree that it's generally cleaner to pass `...` directly. However, it doesn't seem to work with `glm()` and results in `Object wgts not found` error.

Comment: oops, you're totally right, I forgot to forward the caller env :s. The proper function is `value <- function(e) eval(enexpr(e), caller_env())`.

As for `enexprs()`, it is still a bad idea to pass dots this way, you'll get a broken function in many cases. I would add a `weights` argument to `myglm2()` and quote/unquote it within the `glm()` call. And then pass the dots normally.

Comment: Thanks, @lionel. I updated the answer with all your suggestions.