# Cannot find object in function when object is defined with speedglm

Tags: r, function, lazy-evaluation, scoping

I use `speedglm` to fit a GLM to data. When I call the function directly, the code works as expected, but when I create a function to fit the model, I get an error that an argument is not found.

The variable (`w` in the example below) clearly exists in the scope of the function but it seems that the variable is evaluated only later within the speedglm function where w is no longer available or so I think. This is where I start questioning my current understanding of R.

Did I make an error while creating the function, does speedglm use some weird trick to scope the variable (source code [here](https://github.com/cran/speedglm/blob/master/R/speedglm.r)) that breaks the normal (?) logic or do I have a wrong understanding of how R functions work?

I am trying to understand this behavior and also fix my `train_glm` function to make it work with speedglm and weights.

### MWE

```
library(speedglm)

# works as expected
m1 <- speedglm(wt ~ cyl, data = mtcars, weights = mtcars$wt)

# define a small helper function that just forwards its arguments
train_glm <- function(f, d, w) {
  speedglm(formula = f, data = d, weights = w)
}
# does not work
m <- train_glm(wt ~ cyl, d = mtcars, w = mtcars$wt)
#> Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'w' not found
```

Even weirder, if I change the code I found the following

```
# removing the weights as a base case -> WORKS
train_glm3 <- function(f, d) {
  speedglm(formula = f, data = d)
}
m3 <- train_glm3(wt ~ cyl, d = mtcars)
# works


# hardcoding the weights inside the function -> BREAKS
train_glm4 <- function(f, d) {
  speedglm(formula = f, data = d, weights = d$wt)
}
m4 <- train_glm4(wt ~ cyl, d = mtcars)
# Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'd' not found


# creating a new dataset and hardcoding the weights inside the function
# but using the name of the dataset at the highest environment -> WORKS
train_glm5 <- function(f, d) {
  speedglm(formula = f, data = d, weights = mtcars2$wt)
}
mtcars2 <- mtcars
m5 <- train_glm5(wt ~ cyl, d = mtcars2)
# works
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383414/passing-weights-to-glm-using-rlang

Comment: That post shows you how to use non-standard eval to pass weights to glm, I tried with speedglm and it works however because our answers would be the same I would just follow the post above

Answer (score 0):

The solution (thanks to @Mike for the hint) is to evaluate the code either by using the solution given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464137/3048453) or by using `do.call` like so:

```r
library(speedglm)

train_glm_docall <- function(f, d, w) {
  do.call(
    speedglm,
    list(
      formula = f,
      data = d,
      weights = w
    )
  )
}

m2 <- train_glm_docall(f = wt ~ cyl, d = mtcars, w = mtcars$wt)
class(m2)
#> [1] "speedglm" "speedlm"
```