# Order by multiple columns using non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation

Let's say I want to order a `data.frame` using multiple columns and using non-standard evolution. I might have a function that looks something like this

```
my_order <- function(data, ...) {
  with(data, order(...))
}
```

I get an error when I use this function because my columns are not evaluated within the context of `with`.

```
my_order(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
# Error in order(...) : object 'mpg' not found
```

NOTE: I do not wish to use `dplyr::arrange()` for this problem as it adds a dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to wrap the expression into `eval.parent(substitute(...))`:

```
my_order <- function( data, ... ) {
  eval.parent(substitute( with(data, order(...)) ))
}

my_order( mtcars, cyl, mpg )
# [1] 32 21  3  9  8 27 26 19 28 18 20 11  6 10 30  1  2  4 15 16 24  7 17 31 14
# [26] 23 22 29 12 13  5 25
```

Note that we use `eval.parent()` instead of `eval()`, because [eval/substitute combo doesn't play well with nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215820/300187). The `eval.parent()` trick has been [proposed by @MoodyMudskipper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58239679/300187) as a way to address this problem and allows us to seamlessly use `my_order()` inside other functions, including magrittr pipes:

```
mtcars %>% my_order(cyl)
# [1]  3  8  9 18 19 20 21 26 27 28 32  1  2  4  6 10 11 30  5  7 12 13 14 15 16
# [26] 17 22 23 24 25 29 31
```

Comment: One point to note, if you use a parameter with a period, say `.data`, this approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @nathaneastwood: I can't replicate the issue. Using `.data` works just as well as `data` for me.

Comment: So it seems as though it occurs when you try to use `my_order()` in combination with the pipe and it has nothing to do with the name of the variable. So `mtcars %>% my_order(cyl)` will give the error, for example.

Comment: @nathaneastwood: OK, I know what the problem is. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to pass along the unresolved symbols using base R

```
my_order <- function(data, ...) {
  dots <- substitute(...())
  with(data, do.call("order", as.list(dots)))
}
my_order(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
```

Basically we use substitute do capture the symbol names, then use `do.call` to inject those into a call to `order`.

Alternative you could think about re-writing the call to the function and changing the evaulation environment

```
my_order <- function(data, ...) {
  call <-match.call()
  call[[1]] <- quote(order)
  call[2] <- NULL
  eval(call, data, parent.frame())
}
my_order(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
```

Comment: Yep, this is perfect. I was playing around with `do.call` and couldn't quite get it right (I had `do.call(order, list(with(data, ...)))` so almost there). By the way, you can do `do.call(order, as.list(dots))` and I believe it might be slightly faster than quoting the order. Thanks :)