# Select an array of variables using coma to pass these variables into R functions using dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I´m working with functions and dplyr. Codes are based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700912/why-is-enquo-preferable-to-substitute-eval). I would like to pass some variables to the `select` argument of `dplyr` and then perform some analyses. When I use **,** (coma) to separate the list of the variables that I want to select, R fails to print me the results

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100),
                x2 = rnorm(100),
                x3 = rnorm(100),
                x4 = rnorm(100),
                x5 = rnorm(100))
table <- function(items) {
  items <- enquo(items)
  
  pretty <- df %>% 
    select(!!items) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean)
  
  return(pretty)
}

#x1 only!
table(items = x1)
#>           x1
#> 1 0.08593813


#From x1 until X3
table(items = x1:x3)
#>           x1         x2         x3
#> 1 0.08593813 -0.1965462 0.02651688


#From x1 until X2 AND from X4 untill X5 (the real df is different.)
table(items = x1:x2, x4:x5)
#> Error in table(items = x1:x2, x4:x5): unused argument (x4:x5)
Created on 2022-01-13 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to use `enquos` with `!!!`.  For the last case, concatenate (`c`)

```
  table <- function(items) {
     items <- enquos(items)
  
     pretty <- df %>% 
       select(!!!items) %>% 
       summarise_all(mean)
  
     return(pretty)
   }
```

-testing

```
> table(items = x1)
          x1
1 -0.2262251
> table(items = x1:x3)
          x1         x2         x3
1 -0.2262251 0.07106254 0.07618617
> table(items = c(x1:x2, x4:x5))
          x1         x2        x4          x5
1 -0.2262251 0.07106254 0.1151052 -0.06535946
```

NOTE: `table` is a `base R` function.  So, it is better to rename the custom function.  In addition, the suffix `_all`, `_at`, `_each` are all deprecated in favor of `across` i.e. `summarise(across(everything(), mean))`

Comment: You again!! Thank you so much! I'll change the name of the function as well!