# Function says a column is not found

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr

I make this function in R to make a bar graph but it gives me an error every time I try it on a dataset, saying that columname is not found. Can you help me find where the bug is please.

Thanks in advance for your help on how to fix this.

Here is the code:

```
plot_dist <-
  function(data, column_name, title = "Please provide a title") {
    ## This function computes a barplot of a given column_name for a given dataset with the title
    data %>%
      group_by(column_name) %>%
      summarise(Nombre = n()) %>%
      ggplot(aes(column_name, Nombre)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = 'steelblue') +
      geom_text(
        aes(label = Nombre),
        vjust = -0.5,
        color = 'steelblue',
        size = 3.5
      ) +
      theme_minimal() +
      ggtitle(title) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
}
```

For example running:

```
plot_dist(pps, gender, "Distribution de genre")
```

returns

> Error: Column `column_name` is unknown

Comment: Look up `ggplot2` and non-standard evaluation (NSE).

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49648729/786542

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to make this work with [tidyeval](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/) is:

```
...
group_by({{ column_name}} ) %>%
      summarise(Nombre = n()) %>%
      ggplot(aes({{ column_name }}, Nombre)) +
...

plot_dist(mtcars, cyl, "Distribution de cilindros")
```

[image]