# ggplot title from within filtered data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to pass the first value of `Species` column (after filtering) intro the `paste()` command for the `title=`. But this does not work. Could anybody suggest a solution?

It should work for whatever species I select in `filter(...)`

```
iris%>%
  filter(Species=="setosa")%>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title=paste("Length vs Width for ", Species[[1]]))
```

Expected outcome:[image]

Comment: Related: [Adding dynamic chart titles in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336983/adding-dynamic-chart-titles-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have access to the passed data frame within `labs`, since nothing is being piped to it. However, since you are already using the `%>%` operator, you could wrap the ggplot call in curly braces and use the `.` symbol as a stand-in:

```r
iris %>%
  filter(Species=="setosa") %>% {
  ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title=paste("Length vs Width for ", .$Species[1]))
  }
```

[image]