# How to specify arguments in ggplot function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I faced a problem that R does't see the argument I specify in ggplot function. Here is the code I use:

```
s_plot <- function(data, aaa, bbb,){
  ggplot(data, aes(x = aaa, y = bbb))+geom_point(size=2, shape=8, col="red")
}
```

As a result I got an error:

> object aaa not found

What's the problem? How to resolve it?

Thanks a lot.

UPD:

Sorry, but I provide you with the simplest example and it doesn't translate the whole problem. 
Here is the full code I use:

```
s_plot <- function(data, n_after, perc_cap, n_xlab, n_ylab, x_min){
  ggplot(data, aes(x={{n_after}}, y={{perc_cap}})) + geom_point(size=2, shape=8, col="red")+
        xlab(n_xlab)+ ylab(n_ylab)+xlim(x_min, 1.1*max(data$n_after))+  ylim(0, 1.1*max(data$perc_cap))+
    geom_text(aes(x=n_after, y=perc_cap, label = NAME), hjust=0, vjust=-1.5)+
    geom_vline(xintercept=8,  col = "darkgreen",lty=2, size=1)+
    geom_text(aes(x=8, label=label, y=20), colour="steelblue", angle=90, hjust=-1)+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=15),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size=15))
```

As you may see `n_after` and `perc_cap` are mentioned in several places. And this probably is the source of problem. How to resolve it in this particular case?

Comment: See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html#quasiquotation

Comment: How are you trying to call this function? You likely need tidyeval; see the [dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) that should be extendable to ggplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable to specify column name in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot)

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16295234/5325862), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45824409/5325862), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44548819/5325862)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `{{ }}` operator. As in the example:

```
f <- function (data, x) {ggplot(data= data, aes(x={{x}})) + geom_bar()}

f(mtcars, gear)
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't a major issue, but you reversed the data and column arguments from what 1) what the OP shows and 2) standard tidyverse practice which would give you easy access to functions' first arguments